# Access violaton while Reading from a binary file into a char * buffer

Tags: c++

I wrote a binary file using ofstream, starting from an array of float.
When I open it with notepad++ I see a single line of ASCII symbols.
The size shown in File Explorer is 19922944 bytes.

Now I'm trying to read it using ifstream:

```
size_t fileSize = sizeof(char)*19922944; // this value is coherent with the original buffer size and it's the same exact size that I can see from File Explorer
char *fileBuffer = new char(lSize);
std::ifstream iFile("C:\\TheFile.dat", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
iFile.read( fileBuffer, fileSize); // 0xC0000005 Access violation writing location 
iFile.close();
```

If, instead, I read a smaller size, like fileSize=2000, it works well.
But, again, the size on disk is 19922944.
Any idea of what can be wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
char *fileBuffer = new char(lSize);
```

is wrong. It allocates memory for only one `char`. You need to use

```
char *fileBuffer = new char[lSize];
```

It will be preferable to use `std::string` so your code does't have to worry about memory management.

```
std::string fileBuffer(lSize, ' ');
iFile.read(fileBuffer.data(), fileSize);
```

Comment: OMG I'm getting blind. Thank you!

Comment: @HAL9000 A pretty common phenomenon.  You wrote the code, you "know" you wrote it correctly, so you can't "see" the problem.

Comment: Better to use `std::vector` instead of `new[]`

Comment: @RemyLebeau, that too.

Comment: @AndrewHenle that's why it's good (as it happens in a normal company) to have colleagues at working place to ask to have a quick double check ;)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you meant `char *fileBuffer = new char(fileSize);` you're allocating a single character and initializing it with a value that is way too large to store in a single character.

If you enable your compiler's warnings, it is likely to alert you to this sort of problem.

For instance, MSVC 2015 says:

`warning C4267: 'initializing': conversion from 'size_t' to 'char', possible loss of data`